# In wordpress, is there a way to add posts as drafts from the main site, not the admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Have to make something so anybody can add something in the form on the public site, then admin in admin panel will publish it. The post will be a custom type with custom fields and post thumbnail.
So like in a title. Is there a way to make it happen in WordPress?

Found function `*wp_insert_post*` but how to make it work for nonregistered users, also how to upload a picture and add it to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the way to do that.
Simply use '[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)' and plugin '[Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/)', create frontend form in CF7 and map it to custom post type. Needed to do some changes in code but works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would recommend a plugin called Formidable Pro.  With formidable pro, you have the ability to put a front-end form on a website that allows users (logged in or not, depending on how it's setup) to create posts with form submissions.

In the form, you would add fields for all relevant parts of the post (custom fields, title, picture upload, body copy, etc...) then in the settings of the "make post" function in Formidable Pro, attach all the relevant fields to the post content areas (featured image, title, custom fields, etc...).

Formidable Pro can be purchased and downloaded via formidablepro.com (unfortunately the create post feature is a paid-only feature).

Here is their help desk article on creating posts from entries: https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/create-posts/

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107062/how-do-i-make-a-draft-post-accessible-to-everyone?newreg=dd2a01ad300f4b6c90748d0cc13500bd

Comment: @alphagraphics-billings - Found something like it for contact form 7 and is free but require some programming to work like I want.

Comment: @tipanverella - I don't want drafts to be accesible to anyone but admins. Admin moderate and publish that drafts so they are normal published posts.